# C++ Change Included Libraries (Ref DLL's) From Root To Another Location

Tags: c++, visual-studio

All,

I am currently using a couple of libraries for my project. Upon build, in the root of the folder you will see the executable and of course several DLL's which were referenced.

Is it possible to reference these files else where? For an example, if I wanted to move these DLL's to the "\Documents" folder (Now the .exe is alone inside the folder)?

I just want to keep my executable standalone (Or at least have the ability to reference the needed libs elsewhere).

Please let me know a solution to this, or if there is a better way achieve the same goal.

Comment: It is not impossible, just change the Output Directory setting, but your program is not going to run.  Never give the OS a hard time to locate a DLL, the worst kind of DLL Hell is the kind that is self-inflicted.  This is one case where an organized programmer's approach is pretty incompatible with what the OS likes.  Never hide executable code intentionally, users don't like that either.

Comment: Is there a way to pack the binaries into the project?

Answer (score 1):

Polluting the user's machine with DLLs in arbitrary directories strikes me as a bad idea.

If you want to keep the installation directory as neat and human-readable as possible, you can simply squirrel away the DLLs in a sub-directory:

```
my-app\
| - bin\
| | - my_app.exe
| | - some_dll.dll
| | - some_other_dll.dll
| - my_app.exe (shortcut to bin\my_app.exe)
```

Comment: That is one solution. I wish there was a way to pack the binaries of the ref libs inside my project instead, so its not exposed :]